# How to use @AppStorage with CGFloat?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a variable with AppStorage, but I got an error : " No exact matches in call to initializer "

```
  @AppStorage("onTick") var onTick : CGFloat = 1
```

How can I fix it, is there a workaround on this ?

Comment: Store it as a `Double`. `CGFloats` are interchangeable with a `Double`.

Answer (score 3):

As per `@AppStorage` definition you can find the following allowed data types.

- `Bool`
- `Int`
- `String`
- `URL`
- `Double`
- `Data`
- `enum with Int or String`
- `Bool?`
- `Int?`
- `String?`
- `URL?`
- `Double?`
- `Data?`
- `optional enum with Int or String`

You should use `Double` rather than `CGFloat`.